# phpmyadmin simple query sql error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I use php my admin, and i try to run this query :

```
INSERT INTO msumat(tempat_lahir) VALUES ('Jakarta') WHERE umat_id != 10
```

The query should be find, but i always get an error from it :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE umat_id != 10' at line 1
```

Where is my mistake? And i also found some strange fact recently :

a query in my computer is running with the `''` quote BUT this query is NOT running in my friend's computer, i must change the `''` to ``. Is it a bug in phpmyadmin? Thanks :D

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do?!

Comment: An `INSERT` statement has no `WHERE` clause, because you are always adding a new row. Do you mean to `UPDATE` existing rows instead?

Comment: For future reference, it is absolutely almost _never_ a bug in the tool you're using, but rather a fault in your own code :)

Comment: @DannyBeckett it seems i have a miss-understanding about the NULL value :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing an insert and and update.

Inserts create new rows and always provide the values you want to insert.

Updates alter data in a set of rows.

Assuming you mean this to be an update:

```
UPDATE msumat set tempat_lahir = 'Jakarta' where umat_id != 10;
```

Comment: yes, im new to sql. I think because i dont have any value (NULL) in the 'tempat_lahir' column, i need to insert it, not update it. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Please wait for 10 minutes, the system dont allow me to accept the answer now :D

Answer (score 2):

By default, an `INSERT` statement cannot have `WHERE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (column1, ...) VALUES (Value1,...)
```

The only time when an `INSERT` statement can have `WHERE` clause is when you are executing `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (column1, ...)
SELECT column1, ...
FROM   Table_name2
WHERE  ....
```

I guess you want to modify an existing column and you need to use `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE msumat
SET    tempat_lahir = 'Jakarta'
WHERE  umat_id <> 10
```

Always remember this one:

- `INSERT` is always used to **add new** record on the table.
- `UPDATE` is used to **modify** a record on the table.